# How to iterate over unnested html to extract contents in a list format in BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

My problem is kind of specific. I've been looking at all the other BeautifulSoup questions here on SO but have yet to come up with an answer to my issue. I have taken a pdf file and turned it into somewhat decent html with the intention of further transcribing this to a csv file.

My web page i'm working from looks like this, except i redacted a bunch of stuff i wasn't sure i wanted available to the average googler:

```
(RUSI) US Foundation
Last Updated: 2014-12-29
At A Glance
[st # redacted] I St. N.W.
Washington, DC United States 20006
Type of Grantmaker
Independent foundation
Financial Data
(yr. ended 2013-12-31)
Assets: $3,085 Total giving: $0
EIN
[redacted]
990
[redacted]
Application Information
Unsolicited requests for funds not accepted.
Application form not required.
Directors Michael Clarke Sean Murphy Timothy Voake
Financial Data
Year ended 2013-12-31
Assets: $3,085 (market value)
Expenditures: $387
Total giving: $0
Qualifying distributions: $387
Additional Location Information
County: District of Columbia
Metropolitan area: Washington-Arlington-Alexandria, DC-VA-MD-WV Congressional district: District of Columbia District At-large

04Arts Foundation
Last Updated: 2013-05-15
At A Glance
P.O. Box [redacted]
San Antonio, TX United States 78283-1253 Telephone:(210) [redacted] Contact: Penelope Speier URL: www.04arts.org
Type of Grantmaker
Independent foundation
Financial Data
(yr. ended 2012-12-31)
Assets: $40,957 Total giving: $1,698
EIN
[redacted]
990
[redacted]
Additional Contact Information
Application Address: [redacted] Dallas, New Braunfels, TX 78130
Background
Established in 1995 in TX.
Limitations
No grants to individuals.
Fields of Interest Subjects
Arts
Application Information
Application form not required.
Initial approach: Proposal Deadline(s): None
Donor(s)
Note: If a donor is deceased, the symbol (f) follows the name.
Penelope Gallagher William Gallagher Edward Everett Collins, III Edwards Aquifer Authority
Officer
Penelope Speier, Pres.
Directors Wendy W. Atwell Jon Cochran
Financial Data
Year ended 2012-12-31
Assets: $40,957 (market value)
Gifts received: $[redacted] Expenditures: $[redacted] Total giving: $[redacted] Qualifying distributions: $[redacted] Giving activities include:
$[redacted] for grants
Additional Location Information
County: Bexar
Metropolitan area: San Antonio, TX Congressional district: Texas District 35

1 in 9: The Long Island Breast Cancer Action Coalition, Inc
Last Updated: 2011-12-19
At A Glance
[redacted] E. Rockaway Rd.
Hewlett, NY United States 11557-1736 Telephone:(516) [redacted] Fax: (516) [redacted] E-mail: [redacted]
Type of Grantmaker
Public charity
Additional Descriptor
Organization that normally receives a substantial part of its support from a governmental unit or from the general public
EIN
[redacted]
990
[redacted]
Purpose and Activities
The coalition's mission is to promote awareness of the breast cancer epidemic through education, outreach, advocacy, and direct support of research which is being done to find the causes of and cures for breast cancer and other related cancers.
Fields of Interest Subjects
Breast cancer
Breast cancer research
Cancer
Cancer research
Types of Support
Research
Publications
Newsletter
Officers and Directors
Note: An asterisk (*) following an individual's name indicates an officer who is also a trustee or director.
Geri Barish *, Pres.
Louise Levrie, V.P.
Larry Slatky *, Treas.
Caroline Boss Fran Kritchek Frank P. Naudus Leon Newman
Additional Location Information
County: Nassau
Metropolitan area: New York-Northern New Jersey-Long Island, NY-NJ-PA Congressional district: New York District 04
```

My html currently looks like this (exactly like this, so be warned, it's horrid):

```
<p style="text-align:justify;"><span class="font7" style="color:#CB4810;">FOUNDATION</span></p><a name="caption1"></a><h1 style="text-align:justify;"><a name="bookmark0"></a><span class="font7" style="color:#CB4810;"><a href="https://fconline.foundationcenter.org/">DIRECTORY</a></span></h1><div style="float:right;layout-flow:horizontal;">
<p><span class="font4"><a href="https://fconline.foundationcenter.org/grantmaker-profile/save?html_id=54c1468ec37a7">Save this Page</a></span></p></div>
<p style="text-align:justify;"><span class="font1" style="color:#ED977A;">ONLINE </span><span class="font1" style="color:#9D9D9D;">.*&gt;. </span><span class="font1" style="font-weight:bold;color:#9D9D9D;">A </span><span class="font1" style="color:#9D9D9D;">service of the &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="font1" style="color:#808080;">_ </span><span class="font1">...... _</span></p>
<p style="text-align:right;padding:0pt 0pt 23pt 0pt;"><span class="font4" style="text-decoration:underline;">Print this Page</span></p>
<p style="text-align:justify;padding:23pt 0pt 9pt 0pt;"><span class="font4">(</span><span class="font4" style="font-weight:bold;">Refinements: </span><span class="font4">Grantmaker Name: *)</span></p><h2 style="text-align:justify;padding:9pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;"><a name="bookmark1"></a><span class="font6" style="font-weight:bold;">(RUSI) US Foundation</span></h2>
<p style="text-align:justify;padding:0pt 0pt 14pt 0pt;"><span class="font1" style="font-weight:bold;">Last Updated: </span><span class="font2">2014</span><span class="font0">-</span><span class="font2">12-29</span></p><h3 style="text-align:justify;padding:14pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;"><a name="bookmark2"></a><span class="font5" style="font-weight:bold;">At A Glance</span></h3>
<p style="text-align:justify;"><span class="font4">1776 I St. N.W.</span></p>
<p style="text-align:justify;padding:0pt 0pt 9pt 0pt;"><span class="font4">Washington, DC United States 20006</span></p><h4 style="text-align:justify;padding:9pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;"><a name="bookmark3"></a><span class="font4" style="font-weight:bold;">Type of Grantmaker</span></h4>
<p style="text-align:justify;padding:0pt 0pt 9pt 0pt;"><span class="font4">Independent foundation</span></p><h4 style="text-align:justify;padding:9pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;"><a name="bookmark4"></a><span class="font4" style="font-weight:bold;">Financial Data</span></h4>
<p style="text-align:justify;"><span class="font4">(yr. ended 2013-12-31)</span></p>
<p style="padding:0pt 421pt 9pt 0pt;"><span class="font4">Assets: $3,085 Total giving: $0</span></p><h4 style="text-align:justify;padding:9pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;"><a name="bookmark5"></a><span class="font4" style="font-weight:bold;">EIN</span></h4>
<p style="text-align:justify;padding:0pt 0pt 9pt 0pt;"><span class="font4">721374719</span></p><h4 style="text-align:justify;padding:9pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;"><a name="bookmark6"></a><span class="font4" style="font-weight:bold;">990</span></h4>
<p style="text-align:justify;padding:0pt 0pt 9pt 0pt;"><span class="font4"><a href="http://990s.foundationcenter.org/990pf_pdf_archive/721/721374719/721374719_201312_990PF.pdf">2013 </a><a href="http://990s.foundationcenter.org/990pf_pdf_archive/721/721374719/721374719_200412_990PF.pdf">2004</a><a href="http://990s.foundationcenter.org/990_pdf_archive/721/721374719/721374719_200312_990EZ.pdf"> 2003 </a><a href="http://990s.foundationcenter.org/990pf_pdf_archive/721/721374719/721374719_200212_990PF.pdf">2002</a></span></p><h4 style="text-align:justify;padding:9pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;"><a name="bookmark7"></a><span class="font4" style="font-weight:bold;">Application Information</span></h4>
<p style="text-align:justify;padding:0pt 0pt 9pt 0pt;"><span class="font4">Unsolicited requests for funds not accepted.</span></p>
<p style="text-align:justify;padding:9pt 0pt 14pt 0pt;"><span class="font4">Application form not required.</span></p>
<p style="padding:14pt 421pt 14pt 0pt;"><span class="font4" style="font-weight:bold;">Directors Michael Clarke&nbsp;Sean Murphy&nbsp;Timothy Voake</span></p><h4 style="text-align:justify;padding:14pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;"><a name="bookmark8"></a><span class="font4" style="font-weight:bold;">Financial Data</span></h4>
<p style="text-align:justify;padding:0pt 0pt 9pt 0pt;"><span class="font4" style="font-weight:bold;">Year ended 2013-12-31</span></p>
<p style="text-align:justify;padding:9pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;"><span class="font4">Assets: $3,085 (market value)</span></p>
<p style="text-align:justify;"><span class="font4">Expenditures: $387</span></p>
<p style="text-align:justify;"><span class="font4">Total giving: $0</span></p>
<p style="text-align:justify;padding:0pt 0pt 9pt 0pt;"><span class="font4">Qualifying distributions: $387</span></p><h4 style="text-align:justify;padding:9pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;"><a name="bookmark9"></a><span class="font4" style="font-weight:bold;">Additional Location Information</span></h4>
<p style="text-align:justify;"><span class="font4">County: District of Columbia</span></p>
```

Now, when i use BS by running this code;

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

html = Soup(open('found1.html'))
titles = html.find_all('h2', style="text-align:justify;padding:9pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;")
print(titles[0].find(text=True))
print(titles[0].find_next('p', style="text-align:justify;padding:0pt 0pt 14pt 0pt;").\
     find_all(text=True))
print(titles[0].find_next('span', class_="font5",\
                          style="font-weight:bold;").find(text=True))
```

I get;

```
(RUSI) US Foundation
['Last Updated: ', '2014', '-', '12-29']
At A Glance
```

Which is great! The next part i'm having difficulty with. I need to grab everything between 'At A Glance' and 'Type of Grantmaker'. I then need to do this for 'Type of Grantmaker' and the next set. One nice thing about this is that the tags are almost always the same for similar titles. For instance, that's how i can get the name of all the titles with my `titles = html....` code.

My desired output is a list that looks like this:

```
[[first organization, last_updated, at_a_glance, type_of_grantmaker, financial_data, ...], 
[second organization, ...], [third organization, ...], ...]
```

Any steps in the right direction are most appreciated! And if you think my question sucks for whatever reason, i would appreciate a comment along with the -1 so i can fix it. I'm new, and my last questions were not well received...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - the HTML you've provided contains the data for a single organization, correct?

Comment: No, it provides data for a series of organizations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the simplest way for me to do this is by splitting it before putting it into BeautifulSoup. So what i did is split it using the following code and then am (currently) writing a function to deal with breaking text up nicely.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

with open('found1.html', 'r') as f:
    html = f.read()
sections = html.split('</a><span class="font6" style="font-weight:bold;">')


# Developing this bit to extract text cleanly.
def extract(html):
    html = Soup(html)
    html.find_all(text=True)
    print(extract)
    print(html.text)


# Gives me the whole html between the first title and the second
print(sections[1])
extract(sections[1])
```